# Failed to change controlling terminal from xterm to gnome-terminal

Tags: c, codeblocks, xterm, gnome-terminal

I use Code::Blocks as my C/C++ IDE, but the default value of launching console programs is:

```
xterm -T "program name" -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner "program path"
```

I want to change the controlling terminal from xterm to gnome-terminal because of the tiny font size of xterm.

Then, I tried the command for doing this:

```
gnome-terminal -t "program name" -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner "program path"
```

It failed, but the messages below prints to the other gnome-terminal:

```
Usage: cb_console_runner <filename> <args ...>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
gnome-terminal -t "program name" -e '/usr/bin/cb_console_runner "program path"'
```